# Connect AWS CloudFront to Single Sign-On (SSO)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm working on a website deployed to AWS using S3 as storage and CloudFront CDN. It's a static website with a single html file using JS to display the content based on the querystring. The owner is an enterprise that already has established SSO within their organization, they use IBM Tivoli as the IdP. The part I'm missing is how does the request for authorization get generated?

I've read through these:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_saml.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp_saml.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_saml.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_saml_relying-party.html

Many of these are close but just off the mark. It's not an EC2 instance, it's not Elastic Beanstalk, I'm not trying access the AWS console, and they don't use AD for SSO. It's just a website.

So far I have:

- created the SAML provider in AWS and imported the metadata from their IdP
- created the IAM role
- established the trust relationship between role and provider
- established the s3:getObject permission for the role
- provided them with the metadata from AWS with the specifics about the SAML assertions that need to be provided.

My question is how the two sides get connected. Is it automatically done by AWS when anyone attempts to access the site? Does the enterprise create a special link in their portal to start the site with the SAML? What happens if the user just types in the domain name in the browser? Does code need to be added to the website?

TIA,
Mike

Comment: You're citing IAM documentation, which I *think* you'll find is not really going to do what you want, particularly in an SPA.  Read about [AWS Cognito support for SAML identity providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html) and about Cognito in general and see if it doesn't seem like a better match for what you need.

Comment: @sqlbot. Thanks, I'm familiar with cognito. I have another client with an iOS app that gets files from CloudFront and we used cognito for that. However for SAML based SSO it seems that IAM is needed. From the doc... To prepare to create a role for SAML 2.0 federation:

Before you create a role for SAML-based federation, you must create a SAML provider in IAM. For more information, see Creating SAML Identity Providers.

Comment: Maybe.  With IAM & SAML, you're almost certainly going to need a server and I suspect a database,  too, although those could be satisfied with Lambda & DynamoDB if I'm right.  On the flip side, *"You can use an identity provider that supports SAML with Amazon Cognito to provide a simple onboarding flow for your users."*  But of course my intention isn't to argue the point, just explaining what it looks like to me.  You may be quite correct.

Comment: @sqlbot, Thanks again. I finished reading through the doc from your link and there is a certain amount of overlap. There are instructions in the Cognito docs that say I still have to create the IAM role and so forth. I went ahead and created the Cognito identity pool just in case it opens up some new option. However at the very end there's a section on authenticating the user with the IdP... that's the part I need. It provides info on iOS and Android but not JavaScript. Still looking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Circling back to close out this question. I found that AWS doesn't have a way to add an SSO layer to your CloudFront hosted website. That needs to be implemented within the website's code.

I wound up using the npm module 'express-saml' to handle the saml exchange and a really simple DynamoDB table for storing the login on the SP side. The aws-sdk is used for DynamoDB.

Mike

Comment: It seems the recommended approaches now (2019) include either Cognito (for AWS-based auth) or using Lambda@edge to implement a custom authentication provider (I'm struggling with the security/roles around this setup right now). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html https://github.com/nzoschke/gofaas/blob/master/docs/lambda-at-edge-oauth.md